# Remove attribute in all children elements recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<tr id="Estuches_1">
    <td>
        <div class="group">
            <input name="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[0].ProductionOrderId" id="VariableDataList_0__VariableDataForLevel_0__ProductionOrderId" >
            <input name="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[0].AggregationLevelConfigurationId" id="VariableDataList_0__VariableDataForLevel_0__AggregationLevelConfigurationId">
            <select name="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[0].VariableDataId" disabled="disabled" id="VariableDataList_0__VariableDataForLevel_0__VariableDataId">
                <option value="00">Serial Shipping Container Code(SSCC-18)</option>
                <option value="01" selected="">Global Trade Item Number</option>
                <option value="10">Batch or lot number</option>
                <option value="11">Production date(YYMMDD)</option>
                <option value="17">Expiration date(YYMMDD)</option>
                <option value="21">Serial number</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="group">
            <input name="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[0].Value" disabled="disabled" id="VariableDataList_0__VariableDataForLevel_0__Value">
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="VariableDataList[0].VariableDataForLevel[0].Value"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In Javascript, I have a var named `clone` that create with the above html.

I want to remove the attribute `disabled` in all of the elements in the html (one in the select, and another one in the input text).

I have tried this:

```
var clone = $($.parseHTML(html));
clone.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

But it doesn't remove any of them. Maybe, because it is trying to remove the disabled attribute in the `tr`.

How can I remove the `disabled` attribute in all of the elements?

The `id` and the `name` of the elements will change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to target `disabled` element using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and then use [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method

```
clone
    .find('[disabled]') //Target all disabled descendants 
    .removeAttr('disabled') //Remove disabled
```